# How to translate "舔狗" to English?

Tags: translation

This is a popular word in China. I know `舔` means lick, `狗` means dog. But it seems that the meaning of `舔狗` is not to do with `lick`, there is a sentence says `舔狗不得好死`, so I think it's a noun. And according another sentence `舔狗舔到最后一无所有`, I think it can not be translated as licking dog. So how to translate it?

Comment: Looks like a slang. Need more context to guess.

Comment: answered through web search with"舔狗": e.g. http://www.fanjian.net/jbk/tiangou.html

Comment: @user6065 According to your link, it seems that it can be translated to `a flatterer who has no dignity`?

Comment: 两种用法， **一种**  是形容在两性关系中明知道对方不喜欢自己，还一再地毫无尊严和底线地用热脸去贴冷屁股(to show warm feelings but meet with cold rebuke (idiom)
to be snubbed despite showing good intentions)
的人，用更直白粗鄙的叫法我们可以理解为是一种犯贱(行动不自重，显得轻贱骂人的话。指天生的贱骨头，只要人打骂)。**另外** 一种是形容毫无原则和底线去溜须拍马( fawn on; shamelessly flatter)
、阿谀奉承的人。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%88%94%E7%8B%97/22893799?fr=aladdin) defines 舔狗 as:

> “舔狗”，作为网络语的该词，其含义是指代那些无脑去奉承他人的人。通常有两种用法，一种是形容在感情生活中明知道对方不喜欢自己，还一再无底线的讨好对方。另外一种是形容毫无原则去阿谀奉承的人。

As for a translation words like:

- kiss-ass
- brown-noser

should work.

Answer (score 0):

its the chinese version of “simp” LMAO